# Как реализовать справочник в массиве с заполнением через класс Scanner (Java)?

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет!
Я новичок в Java. Изучаю постепенно. Пишу небольшую программу справочник ABS (типа банковская система). Состоит из нескольких классов. Вопрос в следующем. Как мне организовать добавление и удаление информации о пользователе в массиве при выборе (через класс Scanner) через CASE: ADD и DELETE. А также просмотр добавленных пользователей? И в каком лучше классе это сделать или делать отдельный класс под каждый пункт SWITCH?

Пока хочу именно через массив организовать.

На данный момент получилось реализовать в классе menuABS в CASE ADD добавление через геттер, но хочу хранить в массиве.

Спасибо!

```
public class MainABS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        infoStart infoStart = new infoStart();
        menuABS menuABS = new menuABS();
        
        infoStart.infos();
        menuABS.menuABS();

    }

}

public class infoStart {
    
    void infos() {
    
    System.out.println("****************************************************");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("АВТОМАТИЗИРОВАННАЯ БАНКОВСКАЯ СИСТЕМА УЧЕТА КЛИЕНТОВ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("****************************************************");
    }
}


public class Users {
    private String fname = null;
    private String sname = null;
    private String role = null;
    private int usum;
    

    

    public void setfName(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    
    public void setsName(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }
    
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    
    public void getuSum(int usum) {
        this.usum = usum;
    }
    
    public String fName() {
        return fname;
    }
    
    public String sName() {
        return sname;
    }
    
    public String role() {
        return role;
    }
    
    public int uSum() {
        return usum;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class menuABS {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    void menuABS() {
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("SEE - посмотреть информацию о пользователях");
        System.out.println("ADD - добавить пользователя");
        System.out.println("EDIT - редактирование информации о пользователе");
        System.out.println("DELETE - удалить информацию о пользователе");
        System.out.println("ROLE - роли пользователя");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("****************************************************");
        
        System.out.println("Выбор операции: ");
        
        String input = scanner.nextLine(); // ввод пункта меню;
        
        switch(input) {
        case "SEE":
            System.out.println("Заглушка для SEE");
            break;
        
        case "ADD":
            Users users = new Users();
            System.out.println("Введите имя: ");
            String fn = scanner.nextLine();
            users.setfName(fn);
            System.out.println("Введите фамилию: ");
            String sn = scanner.nextLine();
            users.setsName(sn);
            
            System.out.println("Заглушка для ADD");
            break;
            
        case "EDIT":
            System.out.println("Заглушка для EDIT");
            break;
            
        case "DELETE":
            System.out.println("Заглушка для DELETE");
            break;
            
        case "ROLE":
            System.out.println("Заглушка для ROLE");
            break;
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое. Имена классов начинаются с большой буквы (так принято, так удобно читать)
А для добавления и удаления хорошо подходит ArrayList.
в вашем случае будет выглядеть так

```
List usersList = new ArrayList<Users>();
usersList.add(users); //добавляет
usersList.remove(users); //удаляет...
```

Comment: Доброе утро. Да, про имена классов помню. Просто идея пришла в голову и сразу быстро сел писать-торопился))) Спасибо за совет.

Comment: А возможно реализовать через String users[]={}... ? Пока коллекции не изучал, прочитал поверхностно о массивах.

Comment: И где и как инициализировать запись в массив в данном случае? Не понимаю(

Comment: Users[] users = new Users[100];
100 - это максимальное кол-во юзеров...
можешь поставить сколько тебе нужно. (пределы конечно есть)
попробуй циклами.  
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  if (users[i]==null){
    users[i] = new Users(...);
    break:
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
    Users[] allUsers = new Users[100]; 
    Users user = new Users("name","surname"....);
//ADD
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(allUsers[i}==null) {        //проверяем ячейки на пустоту  и если такую находим
            allUsers[i] = user; //присваиваем ячейке нашего юзера
            break; //и прерываем цикл
        }     
    }

//DELETE
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   if(allUsers[i] != null &&  allusers[i].equals(user)){   //убеждаемся что в ячейке есть юзер и сверяем ячейку на совпадение с нашим удаляемым юзером 
      allUsers[i] = null; //и когда находим обнуляем ячейку
      break; // и прерываем цикл
   }
}
```

правда тебе нужно будет переопределить equals() и hashCode()... но это уже другая история

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!